# Publishing Database from Visual Studio Works Fine Locally but has Permission Issues for Remote Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, plesk

Here's my situation.

1. I built a Visual Studio database project (I'm using 2022) and successfully published it locally.
2. I have a low-cost VPS provider that lets me create databases in its Plesk interface.  When I created it, I made a database user with Read/Write permissions and set up my password etc.  I then made a backup of my locally database and imported it via the Plesk interface.  (I didn't want to do it this way... and that's part of my question... see below.)
3. I made my first simple change to the database structure.
4. I easily migrated this change to the local database simply by publishing it again in Visual Studio.  It made the necessary script to update things, and I was happy.
5. BUT when I tried to publish the change to the remote database on the VPS, I get the message

> Failed to import target model to MyDatabase.  Detailed message: The reverse engineering operation cannot continue because you do not have View Definition permission on the 'MyDatabase' database.

So here are my questions:
Clearly I don't have the same permissions on my remote database as on my local one.  Is this something I can address myself my granting my database user account other privileges (In Plesk the only option seems to be "read/write", "read only", and "write only")?  Or are there other permissions setting I can configure in the database itself?  Or do I need to talk to my VPS provider?

The way I got the initial version of my database onto the remote server was to make a backup of it locally and then import it in the Plesk interface.  This seems bad.  But I never could get Visual Studio to publish it for me because of a similar permission issue (with different details - sorry I don't remember the exact error that occurred.)  How should I publish it?  And more importantly how should I make subsequent changes to it?

Thanks in advance for any advice.